# How can I limit returned fields in aldeed tabular

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatable

I have a Products collection that has attributes including invoicePrice. Is there a way I can set up my aldeed tabular datatable so it does not return invoicePrice? Looking through the aldeed tabular documentation, I was only able to find how to select which fields to return - something like:

```
selector: function ()
{
 return {author: "Agatha Christine"};
};
```

What I need is something to choose what NOT to return - something along the lines of:

```
selector: function ()
{
   {invoicePrice: 0};
};
```

Initially, I tried to limit the return fields by using my publish/subscription functions. I realized that aldeed tabular actually bypasses my publish/subscription functions when I commented out my publish function for Products.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can select which fields NOT to return?

Thanks!

Comment: The selector on author name is not limiting which fields to return.  It limits the documents returned to only those with that author name.  The same fields are returned.  Are you looking for the reverse of that, e.g., "show me all documents that have invoicePrice not equal to zero", or are you trying to not include that field at all in the data that is sent to the client?

Comment: Hi Mark - I am looking for something like "Show me all attributes except invoicePrice, size, etc."

Comment: Have you tried using a custom publish function as described here?: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken you can set that up on your "Meteor.publish" block!

Example:

```
Meteor.publish('productsWithFewerFields', function(){
    return Products.find({}, {fields: {
        invoicePrice: false
    }});
});
```

Comment: Hi - I tried that already without luck.. Again, I think it's because aldeed tabular bypasses the publish/subscribe functions.